# Are books good for anything?

Tags: pitman

Every now and then I find a book.

- I can pick the book up.
- I can carry the book around.
- I can even read the book!

This book is called *About Dwarves*.

[image: About Dwarves]

This appears to be lore from the game world.  There was also a humourous book on the first floor that listed the top five causes of death for Dwarves in the mines.

Aside from this entertaining and interesting trivia, is there anything else books can be used for?  Is there any reason for me to want to fill up one or more of my inventory slots carrying them around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience and reading around other forums, no.
 They seem to just have short stories to give the game a slightly more realistic affect.